# Using Onsen UI Theme Roller and Monaca Cloud

Tags: onsen-ui, monaca

I've customized a theme using Onsen UI Theme Roller and now I have the customized .styl and .css files.
I'm using Monaca Cloud to develop my app, and I don't understand where to put the customized css file. Is it enough to put my customized "onsen-css-components.min.css" in css folder and load it from the html? It seems that if I'll follow this way I'll not be able to respect these guidelines: http://onsen.io/blog/tutorial-customizing-onsen-ui-themes/

Thanks

Comment: In Monaca, Onsen UI CSS is loaded in the file `components/loader.css`. You can import your own CSS in that file (removing the default style lines) or you can include it directly in `index.html` (removing the link to `loader.css`), as you prefer.

Comment: Hi thanks. So it's recommended to keep .styl file for further updates as described [here](http://onsen.io/blog/tutorial-customizing-onsen-ui-themes/), isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's better to keep it in case you need to modify something, but Monaca won't use it directly (just the generated CSS).